# Using Mantel to explore relationship between geographic distance and a multivariate character

Tags: r, regression, correlation, distance-functions, cochran-mantel-haenszel

I'm working with bird songs. A song is composed of many vocal parameters [highest frequency (Hz), lower frequency(Hz), bandwidth(Hz), duration (s), number of notes, and son on....]

**I'm interested in exploring the relationship between geographical distance and bird songs, to see if some pattern of variation exist in this relationship.**

**Here is what I did to analyse these songs:**

I calculated the distance between each value sampled for each parameter and than generated a matrix of dissimilarity for each parameter measured using euclidean distance. Than I performed a Mantel's Test for each parameter, using a matrix of geographical distance between sampling points and a matrix of distance between values sampled at each point for a given vocal parameter.

**My question is:
Is this data analyses correct? Some os these parameters are correlated (like number of notes and song duration, and high frequency with bandwidth), so am I falling into the problem of dependence and pseudoreplication?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert. I also don't know if your song variables are measured at the individual or species-level. Assuming the latter (if former, a simple thing would be to average to species and pick up directions from here), I would suggest running a PCA where rows are species and song elements are columns. Then pull out each species' position in however many dimensions you care to use (you'll have as many as you have song elements I think). That matrix would just be rows as species, columns as position along each successive PC axis.

Then you can simply run

```
distancesAmong <- dist(pca.position.matrix)
```

And a Mantel test between these distances and the geographic distances. Make sure the matrices are in the same order, obviously. There are additional distance measures you can use, the default is Euclidean.